# Не получается построить дерево категорий

Tags: php

Никак не могу построить дерево категорий.
Вот структура массива и код.

```
$cat[] = [
    'categoryID' => '1266',
    'parentID' => '1',
    'name' => 'Смартфоны, связь, навигация'
];

$cat[] = [
    'categoryID' => '1290',
    'parentID' => '1266',
    'name' => 'Аксессуары к мобильным телефонам'
];

$cat[] = [
    'categoryID' => '1291',
    'parentID' => '1290',
    'name' => 'Чехлы для мобильных телефонов'
];

$cat_tree = [];
foreach($cat as $v){

    if($v['parentID'] == 1){
        if(!isset($cat_tree[$v['categoryID']])){
            $cat_tree[$v['categoryID']] = [
                'categoryID' => $v['categoryID'], 
                'parentID' => $v['parentID'], 
                'name' => $v['name'], 
                'level2' => []
            ];
        }
    }

    if(isset($cat_tree[$v['parentID']])){
        $cat_tree[$v['parentID']]['level2'][$v['categoryID']] = [
            'categoryID' => $v['categoryID'], 
            'parentID' => $v['parentID'], 
            'name' => $v['name'], 
            'level3' => []
        ];
    }

    if(isset($cat_tree[1266] ['level2'][$v['parentID']])){

        $cat_tree[1266]['level2'][$v['parentID']]['level3'][$v['categoryID']] = [
            'categoryID' => $v['categoryID'], 
            'parentID' => $v['parentID'], 
            'name' => $v['name']
        ];
    }
}
print_r($cat_tree); die;
```

Пробую построить дерево, на третьем уровне вложенности никак не получается сделать. 
В коде прописал ключ (захардкодил), так работает.
Подскажите как нормально сделать?

Вот так хочется чтоб было
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вся сложность из-за динамического поля `level`, пытался уменьшить код и упростить его, получилось следующее:

```
<?php

$cat[] = [
    'categoryID' => '1266',
    'parentID' => '1',
    'name' => 'Смартфоны, связь, навигация'
];

$cat[] = [
    'categoryID' => '1290',
    'parentID' => '1266',
    'name' => 'Аксессуары к мобильным телефонам'
];

$cat[] = [
    'categoryID' => '1291',
    'parentID' => '1290',
    'name' => 'Чехлы для мобильных телефонов'
];

function createTree($input)
{
    $result = [];

    // Данные которые будут использоваться для построения дерева.
    $parentId = 1;
    $level    = 1;
    $parts     = [];
    // Небольшая страховка, можно убрать или изменить число
    $count = 0;
    while (!empty($input) || $count > 20) {
        foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
            if ($value['parentID'] != $parentId) {
                continue;
            }
            // Обновляем данные которые нужны для построения дерева.
            $parentId = $value['categoryID'];
            $level++;

            // Добавляем новый элемент в дерево.
            $item = $value;
            $item["level$level"] = [];
            if (empty($parts)) {
                $result[$parentId] = $item;
            } else {
                $array = &$result;
                foreach ($parts as $part) {
                    $array = &$array[$part];
                }
                $array[$parentId] = $item;
            }
            array_push($parts, $parentId, 'level' . $level);

            // Этот элемент массива нам больше не нужен.
            unset($input[$key]);
            break;
        }
        $count++;
    }

    return $result;
}

print_r(createTree($cat));
```

Вывод следующий:

```
Array
(
    [1266] => Array
        (
            [categoryID] => 1266
            [parentID] => 1
            [name] => Смартфоны, связь, навигация
            [level2] => Array
                (
                    [1290] => Array
                        (
                            [categoryID] => 1290
                            [parentID] => 1266
                            [name] => Аксессуары к мобильным телефонам
                            [level3] => Array
                                (
                                    [1291] => Array
                                        (
                                            [categoryID] => 1291
                                            [parentID] => 1290
                                            [name] => Чехлы для мобильных телефонов
                                            [level4] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Спасибо, но работает не совсем корректно. Если добавить еще такой же массив, то зависает в бесконечном цикле. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/11eb28aa2e6e6f0b6eae4183dad45df6ede1ef40

Comment: @Faust Ну под этот пример работать не будет, тут суть меняется тогда в новом примере, оказывается может быть несколько родительских категорий, я делал под одну, по сути с этой логикой там нужно не много изменений и будет работать

Comment: Хорошо, попробую разобраться как адаптировать тот код, если несколько родительских категорий. Их там несколько десятков

Comment: @Faust а в чём проблема найти все категории у которых родитель = 1 и циклом пройтись по ним с помощью функции? На выходе будет то что вы хотите.